# Determining if sets of objects are vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm going through my textbook and got to the section which deals with vectors in real space. And I'm asked to verify that the set:

$(x,y,z) + (x', y', z') = (x + x', y + y', z + z')$

and

$k(x,y,z) = (kx,y,z)$

I understand the ten axioms which define a vector, however the problem I am having is that I'm not sure how to apply these theorems. My textbook doesn't show examples, or if it does they're very basic and obvious. The only example for the section is two, 2x2 matrices, which I have no problem proving each axiom for. Can anyone explain how to solve for the type of question above, and give me some tips for finding how to solve questions that aren't exactly obvious?

Answer (score 4):

You won't have a vector space because in a vector space $0v = (0+0)v = 0v + 0v$, hence $0v = 0$, which will not hold because $0(x,y,z) = (0,y,z) \neq 0$ for $y \neq 0$ or $z \neq 0$.

The axiom that will fail will be precisely the distributivity over addition of scalars : 
$$
(k_1 + k_2)(x,y,z) = ((k_1+k_2)x,y,z) \neq (k_1x,y,z) + (k_2x,y,z) = k_1(x,y,z) + k_2(x,y,z).
$$
What you should understand when you try to verify if under some operations a set because a vector space, is simply try to prove if the axioms of a vector space hold. In this case only this precise axiom fails.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thanks for the response, my only question is why is 0(x,y,z) = (0,y,z)? Shouldn't it be (0x, 0y, 0z)?

Comment: @user Did you miss-type the scalar multiplication, meaning $k(x, y, z) = (kx, ky, kz)$? Patrick is informing you that if multiplication by $k$ yields **what you wrote in your question:** that $k(x, y, z)$ is defined to be $(kx, y, z)$, then it is not a vector space. Note the difference between the two equalities I've included here in the comment. If you **meant** $k(x, y, z) = (kx, ky, kz)$, then the axioms all hold. But in that case, edit your post!

Comment: Oh no, sorry, I had confused myself. I understand what Patrick means now, thanks.

Comment: user... Okay, good. Just wanted to make sure we're "all on the same page" ;-) @Patrick: (+)